# How to print instance name that do not match numerically between 2 files?

Tags: perl, comparison, numerical

I would like to compare 2 files numerically for each instance name and output any mismatch property.

Ref.txt:

```
CELLA CELLA 0.0000 0.0000 0 0 50 47 100 390 798 1000 3349 2938
CELLA/I0/I0 INV 0.0200 0.2210 0 0 20 200 30 100 430 770 230 940
CELLA/I0/I2 INV 1.0400 0.2210 0 0 530 200 250 261 1230 670 1240 390
```

New.txt:

```
CELLA CELLA 0.0000 0.0000 0 0 50 47 100 390 798 1000 3349 2938
CELLA/I0/I2 INV 1.0400 0.2218 0 0 530 200 250 261 1230 670 1240 390
CELLA/I0/I0 INV 0.0200 0.2210 0 0 20 200 30 100 430 770 230 940
```

Expected Output(CELLA/I0/I2 which 0.2218 is not equal to 0.2210):

```
-ERROR: CELLA/I0/I2 has mismatch property.
```

My code so far,how should I fix my code?

```
use strict;

my %hash;

sub read_hash {
  my $fname = shift;
  open(my $fh, "<", $fname) or die "$!";
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($occurname, $tempname, $x, $y, $reflection, $rotation, $xy1, $xy2, $xy3,$xy4,  
 $xy5, $xy6, $xy7, $xy8, $xy9, $xy10, $xy11, $xy12, $xy13) = split /\s+/, $fh;
  }
}

my %hash1 = read_hash("Ref.txt");
my %hash2 = read_hash("New.txt");

if ($hash1{$x}{$y}{$reflection}{$rotation}{$xy1}{$xy2}{$xy3}{$xy4}{$xy5}{$xy6}{$xy7}{$xy8}{$xy9}{$xy10}{$xy11}{$xy12}{$xy13}
    != $hash2{$x}{$y}{$reflection}{$rotation}{$xy1}{$xy2}{$xy3}{$xy4}{$xy5}{$xy6}{$xy7}{$xy8}{$xy9}{$xy10}{$xy11}{$xy12}{$xy13}) {
  print "$occurname has mismatch property";
}
else {
  print "Match\n";
}
```

Comment: Well you could start by formatting your code so that it's *readable*. I've done it for you this time, but please use white space, especially *indentation*, to make the structure and meaning of your code more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I'm not inclined to work through your code explaining all the problems. The biggest error is that *nested hashes don't work like that*. Here is a complete revision that does what you ask.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %ref_data;

open my $fh, '<', 'Ref.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($occurname, $tempname, @data) = split;
  $ref_data{$occurname} = \@data;
}

open $fh, '<', 'New.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  my ($occurname, $tempname, @data) = split;
  my $ref_data = $ref_data{$occurname};
  unless ($ref_data and grep($data[$_] != $ref_data->[$_], 0..$#data) == 0) {
    print "$occurname has mismatch property\n";
  }
}
```

**output**

```
CELLA/I0/I2 has mismatch property
```

Comment: An error occur where 0.26 is not equal to 0.2600. I change eq to == but there are still error occur.

Comment: I really wish to know what is this command line about.
unless ($ref_data and grep($data[$_] != $ref_data->[$_], 0..$#data) == 0)

Comment: @annel: Okay I've fixed it. *Please* make some effort of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from your sub read_hash.

Add something like `$hash{$x}{$y}.... =  $occurname;`  in the while loop and `return %hash` at the end of the sub.

Comment: The OP doesn't want a seventeen-level hash. The intention seems to be to make sure that *all columns* from the third onwards are the same for a given value of the first column. Using the data as hash keys doesn't help at all.